# Bizarre email sent from spam email address with contact details of someone I know and a friend of their's in it

Tags: email, spam

Someone I know (call them Darren Smith) recently received a rather odd email. It was sent to their personal email address, emailaddresswithnonameinit@emailprovider.com. The "From" field had "Darren Smith" as the name in it, but the actual email address was ninerandomlettersandnumbers@differentemailprovider.com.

The text of the email is this:

```
NameOfDarren'sFriend, Are you free at the moment?

Regards,
Darren Smith
```

I have no idea what this could be, how whatever this is got the name of the person Darren knows, or how it got Darren's original email address. Anyone have any insight as to what sort of attack this is, and what steps should be taken now?

Comment: Information like this could for example come from hacked friends, hacked shops but also could be resold by some shops for advertisement. Since we know nothing about Darren and all the places where he left his name and email I propose to close this question as too broad.

Comment: Indeed it could be many things, including compromised friend-of-a-friend PC. I concur with closing, but it's definitely not a legit e-mail.

Comment: If the mail ended up in Darren's inbox while suggesting it was sent *by* Darren *to* somebody else, the attacker apparently made some mistake. Anyway, this kind of attack requires only to find out about one person's name and email address and the name of a likely acquainted person. Such info would be available e.g. in the contact list owned by a common friend. - A more professional (and today common) variant puts additional research into the roles and relations: "Dear <accounting person>, please transfer XXX $ to <some account>. Regards <sender name = CEO>. P.S.: Do not inform board members"

Answer (score 2):

This is a common phishing scam. It is *meant* to work like this:

1. Mallory is a baddie and figures out that Alice knows Bob. (Lots of ways this can be done, classic examples are looking on LinkedIn or reading employee lists published on the web.) Often Bob is Alice's grandboss or similar.
2. Mallory sends a mail to Alice, using a free email account with something close to Bob's name, asking if they are available.
3. Alice doesn't look too close at the mail, thinks it is genuinely from big boss Bob, and replies.
4. Mallory does some social engineering, telling Alice a story such as "I am stuck in a meeting, can only email, need to get someone important a last minute present, buy some amazon vouchers and send them to me, I will pay you back from work funds."
5. Alice buys and sends the vouchers and Mallory's scam has been successful.

There is an extra factor to what you've seen with Darren. Mallory in this case is not terribly bright and has mixed up Darren and Darren's friend.

The correct response is not to respond to the email.